# JButton Keyboard - convert setText to char

Tags: java, string, keyboard, char, jbutton

I am trying to use a JButton based keyboard in a GUI based game of Hangman.  However when I want to check that the key pressed is in the hidden word, I am not sure where I need to change the type from String to char.  I want to use the GUI based keyboard instead of allowing the user to use the keyboard, to try and minimise the validation that needs to be done.  These are the classes that I have created thus far.  I am struggling to get this working.

```
package guis;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MouseClick extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static ActionListener letterHandler = null;
private Container cPane;
private JLabel lblTitle, lblTries, lblCountryToGuess, chancesLabel, message;//, usedLettersPanel;
private JButton btnExit, btnStart, btn1, btn3, btn4, btnX;
private JButton [] btn = new JButton[26];
private JPanel pNorth, pSouth, pEast, pWest, pCenter, wordPanel, messagePanel, usedLettersPanel, hangPanel, drawingFrame;//, lblCountryToGuess;
private JMenuItem mIRules, mIDev, mIRestart, mIExit;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu3;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem4;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem5;
private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator1;
private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
private JButton enter;
private JLabel[] wordArray, usedLetters;
//private JFrame drawingFrame;
private HangmanDrawing drawing;
private char[] incorrectGuesses;
private char[] buttonLetters =  {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
private String word;
private int chances;
char input;

private JFrame endFrame;
private JPanel top, bottom;
private JLabel doNow;
private JButton restart, exit;

MouseClick() throws IOException
{
    super("Assignment 2 - Hangman");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    word = new WordHandler().getRandomWord();
    chances = 7;

    cPane = getContentPane();
    cPane.setBackground(new Color (236, 128, 19));

    pNorth = new JPanel();
    pSouth = new JPanel();
    pEast = new JPanel();
    pWest = new JPanel();
    pCenter = new JPanel();

    lblTitle = new JLabel(" Hangman ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblTitle.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 24));
    lblTitle.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
    lblTitle.setBackground(new Color (38, 29, 226));
    lblTitle.setOpaque(true);
    lblTitle.setForeground(Color.white);
    pNorth.add(lblTitle);

    /*lblCountryToGuess = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblCountryToGuess.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 24));
    //lblCountryToGuess.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 15, 5));
    lblCountryToGuess.setBounds(50, 1, 500, 60);
    lblCountryToGuess.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("This is the country to be guessed..."));
    //wordArray = new JLabel [hiddenCountry.length()];
    //for (int i = 0 ; i < wordArray.length ; i++) 
    //{
       // wordArray[i] = new JLabel("_");
       // wordArray[i].setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS.", Font.BOLD, 23));
       // lblTitle4.add(wordArray[i]);
    //}
    pCenter.add(lblCountryToGuess);*/

    hangPanel = new HangmanDrawing();
    //drawing = new HangmanDrawing();
    drawingFrame = new JPanel();
    //drawingFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    //drawingFrame.setFocusableWindowState(false);
    //drawingFrame.getContentPane().add(drawing);
    //int xPosition = (int) ((scrnsize.width / 2) + (this.getWidth() / 2));
    //drawingFrame.setSize(scrnsize.width - xPosition - 10,
        //scrnsize.width - xPosition - 10);
   // drawingFrame.setLocation(xPosition, 
        //(int) (scrnsize.height - this.getHeight())/3);

    setVisible (true);
    drawingFrame.setVisible(true);
    pCenter.add(drawingFrame);

    wordPanel = new JPanel();
    wordPanel.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 60);
    wordPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 15, 5));
    wordPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("This is the country to guess..."));
    wordArray = new JLabel [word.length()];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < wordArray.length ; i++) 
    {
        wordArray[i] = new JLabel("_");
        wordArray[i].setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 23));
        wordPanel.add(wordArray[i]);
    }
    pCenter.add(wordPanel);

    usedLettersPanel = new JPanel();
    usedLettersPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 13, 5));
    incorrectGuesses = new char [chances];
    usedLetters = new JLabel [incorrectGuesses.length];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < usedLetters.length ; i++) 
    {
        usedLetters[i] = new JLabel("~");
        usedLetters[i].setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 18));
        usedLettersPanel.add(usedLetters[i]);
    }
    pCenter.add(usedLettersPanel);

    messagePanel = new JPanel();
    messagePanel.setLayout (new FlowLayout (FlowLayout.LEFT));
    message = new JLabel ("Guess a letter...");
    message.setFont (new Font ("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 17));
    messagePanel.add(message);
    pCenter.add(messagePanel);

    /*usedLettersPanel = new JLabel();
    usedLettersPanel.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 24));
    usedLettersPanel.setBounds(50, 1, 500, 60);
    usedLettersPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Letters already guessed..."));
    //usedLettersPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 13, 5));
    //incorrectGuesses = new char [chances];
    //usedLetters = new JLabel [incorrectGuesses.length];
    //for (int i = 0 ; i < usedLetters.length ; i++) 
    //{
        //usedLetters[i] = new JLabel("~");
        //usedLetters[i].setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 18));
        //usedLettersPanel.add(usedLetters[i]);
    //}
    pCenter.add(usedLettersPanel);*/

    btnStart = new JButton(" Start / New Game ");
    btnStart.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 12));
    btnStart.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    btnStart.setForeground(Color.white);
    btnStart.setOpaque(true);
    btnStart.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
    pWest.add(btnStart);

    btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            dispose();
            jMenuItem1.setVisible(true);
            MouseClick sample = null;
            try 
            {
                sample = new MouseClick();
            } 
            catch (IOException e1) 
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            sample.setTitle("Assignment 2 - Hangman Game");
            sample.setSize(1200, 800);
            sample.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            sample.setVisible(true);
        }// end actionPerformed method
    });

    chancesLabel = new JLabel (chances + " chances left...");
    chancesLabel.setFont (new Font ("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 17));
    //lblTries = new JLabel(" Tries Remaining ");
    //lblTries.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 12));
    chancesLabel.setBackground(new Color (38, 29, 226));
    chancesLabel.setForeground(Color.white);
    chancesLabel.setOpaque(true);
    chancesLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
    pWest.add(chancesLabel);

    btnExit = new JButton(" Exit Game");
    btnExit.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 12));
    btnExit.setBackground(new Color (236, 19, 35));
    btnExit.setForeground(Color.white);
    btnExit.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
    pWest.add(btnExit);

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        //JButton btnX = new JButton();
        btnX = new JButton(new KeyboardListener(buttonLetters[i]));
        btnX.setText("" + buttonLetters[i]);
        pSouth.add(btnX);
        btnX.setVisible(true);
        //btn[i] = btnX;
        //btn[i].setText("" + (char)('A'+ i));
        //btn[i].setText("" + buttonLetters[i]);
        //input = buttonLetters[i];
        //pSouth.add(btn[i]);
        //btn[i].setVisible(true);

    }

    cPane.add(pNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    cPane.add(pSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pSouth.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,10,1,1));
    cPane.add(pWest, BorderLayout.WEST);
    pWest.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1,1,10));
    cPane.add(pEast, BorderLayout.EAST);
    cPane.add(pCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pCenter.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1, 1, 1));

    /*Container chancesContainer = new Container();
    chancesContainer.setLayout(new FlowLayout (FlowLayout.RIGHT));
    chancesContainer.add(chancesLabel);

    JPanel wrongGuessesContainer = new JPanel();
    wrongGuessesContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout (1, 2));
    wrongGuessesContainer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder ("Wrong Guesses"));
    wrongGuessesContainer.add(usedLettersPanel);
    wrongGuessesContainer.add (chancesContainer);

    Container bottomContainer = new Container();
    bottomContainer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    bottomContainer.add(wrongGuessesContainer, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    bottomContainer.add(messagePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //getContentPane().add (inputPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    getContentPane().add(wordPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(bottomContainer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);*/

    btnExit.addActionListener(this);

    pCenter.addMouseListener(this);
    pNorth.addMouseListener(this);
    pSouth.addMouseListener(this);
    pEast.addMouseListener(this);
    pWest.addMouseListener(this);   

    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem3 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
    jMenuItem4 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenu3 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem5 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    jMenu1.setText("File");

    jMenuItem1.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_N, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    jMenuItem1.setText("New Game");
    jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            dispose();
            jMenuItem1.setVisible(true);
            MouseClick sample = null;
            try 
            {
                sample = new MouseClick();
            } 
            catch (IOException e1) 
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            sample.setTitle("Assignment 2 - Hangman Game");
            sample.setSize(1200, 800);
            sample.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            sample.setVisible(true);
        }// end actionPerformed method
    });
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    jMenu2.setText("Help");

    jMenuItem3.setText("Rules");
    jMenuItem3.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Hangman is a guessing game where the word"
                +"\n to guess is represented by dashes.  The player"
                +"\n is given the option to enter a letter.  If the letter"
                +"\n guessed is contained in the word, the letter will"
                +"\n replace the dash in its approprate placement."
                +"\n You cannot exceed 7 wrong guesses or else you"
                +"\n lose.  Words are selected randomly.", "Instructions",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    });
    jMenu2.add(jMenuItem3);
    jMenu2.add(jSeparator1);

    jMenuItem4.setText("Developer");
    jMenuItem4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Developer: Ryan Smith");
        }
    });
    jMenu2.add(jMenuItem4);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

    jMenu3.setText("Exit");

    jMenuItem5.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F4, java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
    jMenuItem5.setText("Exit Game");
    jMenuItem5.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    jMenu3.add(jMenuItem5);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu3);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    pack();

    /*drawing = new HangmanDrawing();
    drawingFrame = new JFrame();
    drawingFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    drawingFrame.setFocusableWindowState(false);
    drawingFrame.getContentPane().add(drawing);
    int xPosition = (int) ((scrnsize.width / 2) + (this.getWidth() / 2));
    drawingFrame.setSize(scrnsize.width - xPosition - 10,
        scrnsize.width - xPosition - 10);
    drawingFrame.setLocation(xPosition, 
        (int) (scrnsize.height - this.getHeight())/3);

    setVisible (true);
    drawingFrame.setVisible(true);*/
}

private void endGame()
{
       enter.removeActionListener (this);
       //inputField.removeActionListener(this);
       //inputField.setEditable (false);

       endFrame = new JFrame();
       top = new JPanel();
       bottom = new JPanel();
       doNow = new JLabel ("What do you want to do now?");
       restart = new JButton ("Start Again");
       exit = new JButton ("Exit Hangman");

       doNow.setFont (new Font ("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 17));
       top.setLayout (new FlowLayout (FlowLayout.CENTER));
       top.add (doNow);

       restart.setFont (new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
       restart.addActionListener(this);
       exit.setFont (new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
       exit.addActionListener(this);

       bottom.setLayout (new FlowLayout (FlowLayout.CENTER, 44, 10));
       bottom.add (restart);
       bottom.add (exit);

       endFrame.getContentPane().setLayout (new BorderLayout());
       endFrame.getContentPane().add (top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
       endFrame.getContentPane().add (bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
       endFrame.pack();
       Dimension scrnsize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
       endFrame.setLocation ((int) (scrnsize.width - endFrame.getWidth())/2,
           (int) (scrnsize.height - this.getHeight())/3 + this.getHeight());
       endFrame.setResizable (false);
       endFrame.setVisible (true);
       this.setFocusableWindowState(false);
   }

   public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) 
   {
       if(event.getSource().equals(btnExit))
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
       else if (event.getSource().equals(restart)) 
       {
           endFrame.dispose();
           MouseClick.this.dispose();
           //drawingFrame.dispose();
           //new HangmanMenu();
       } 
       else if (event.getSource().equals(exit)) 
       {
           endFrame.dispose();
           MouseClick.this.dispose();
           //drawingFrame.dispose();
           System.exit(0);
       } 
       else 
       {
           try 
           {
               //char input = Character.toUpperCase(inputField.getText().charAt(0));
               //if(event.getSource().equals(btn))
               //{
                   //System.out.println("\n" + input);
                   boolean letterInWord = false;
                   for (int i = 0 ; i < word.length() ; i++) 
                   {
                       if (word.charAt (i) == input) 
                       {
                           letterInWord = true;
                           break;
                       }
                   }
                   if (!letterInWord) {
                   boolean alreadyGuessed = false;
                   for (int i = 0 ; i < incorrectGuesses.length ; i++) {
                       if (incorrectGuesses [i] == input) {
                           alreadyGuessed = true;
                           message.setText ("You already guessed that!");
                           break;
                       }
                   }
                   if (!alreadyGuessed) {
                       chances--;
                       drawing.addPart();
                       if (chances >= 0) {
                            incorrectGuesses [incorrectGuesses.length - chances - 1] = input;
                            usedLetters [usedLetters.length - chances - 1].setText ("" + input);
                            message.setText ("Woops, wrong! Try again!");
                            chancesLabel.setText (chances + " chances left...");
                       } else {
                            chancesLabel.setText ("Sorry, you lose.");
                            message.setText ("The word was: " + word);
                            endGame();
                       }
                   }
               } else {
                   boolean alreadyGuessed = false;
                   for (int i = 0 ; i < wordArray.length ; i++) {
                       if (wordArray [i].getText().charAt (0) == input) {
                           alreadyGuessed = true;
                           message.setText ("You already guessed that!");
                           break;
                       }
                   }
                   if (!alreadyGuessed) {
                       for (int i = 0 ; i < word.length() ; i++) {
                           if (word.charAt (i) == input) {
                               wordArray [i].setText ("" + input);
                           }
                       }
                       boolean wordComplete = true;
                       for (int i = 0 ; i < wordArray.length ; i++) {
                           if (!Character.isLetter (wordArray [i].getText().charAt (0))) {
                               wordComplete = false;
                               break;
                           }
                       }
                       if (!wordComplete) {
                           message.setText ("Well done, you guessed right!");
                       } else {
                           message.setText ("Congratulations, you win the game!");
                           drawing.escape();
                           endGame();
                       }
                   }
               //}
               }
               //inputField.setText ("");
           }catch (Exception x) 
           {
           }
       }
   }

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}   

class KeyboardListener implements ActionListener
{
    private final char letter;

    public KeyboardListener(char letter)
    {
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    public char getLetter()
    {
        return letter;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        char tempLetter;

        if (e.getSource().equals(btnX))
        {
            tempLetter = 'A';

        }
    }
}
```

}
This is the code for the WordHandler class.

```
package guis;

import java.io.*;

class WordHandler 
{

private BufferedReader fileIn;
private String[] wordArray;
private File wordFile;

public WordHandler() throws IOException 
{
    wordFile = new File("countriesnospaces.txt");
    int arrayCounter = 0;
    try {
            BufferedReader fileIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(wordFile));

            while (fileIn.readLine() != null)
            {
                arrayCounter++;
            }
            wordArray = new String [arrayCounter];
            fileIn.close();

            fileIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(wordFile));
            for (int pos = 0 ; pos < arrayCounter ; pos++) 
            {
                wordArray[pos] = fileIn.readLine();
            }
            fileIn.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("File not found. Please create it and add words.");
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
}

public String getRandomWord() throws IOException 
{
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * wordArray.length);
    return wordArray[random].toUpperCase();
}

public void sort() 
{
    String temp;
    for (int loop = 0 ; loop < wordArray.length - 1 ; loop++) {
        for (int pos = 0 ; pos < wordArray.length - 1 - loop ; pos++) {
            if (wordArray[pos].compareTo(wordArray[pos + 1]) >0) {
                temp = wordArray[pos];
                wordArray[pos] = wordArray[pos + 1];
                wordArray[pos + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

public String[] getArray() 
{
    return wordArray;
}
}
```

This is the test class.

```
package guis;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TestMouseClick 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    MouseClick sample = new MouseClick();
    sample.setTitle("Assignment 2 - Hangman");
    sample.setSize(800, 750);
    sample.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    sample.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: what you have in country array ?

Comment: The country is a random country read in from a txt file as a string.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix would be getting the first character in the String returned by JButton tooltip text using the `charAt(0)` method and assign it to input:

```
char input = jButton26.getToolTipText().charAt(0);
```

or you could split it up to make it clearer:

```
String s = jButton26.getToolTipText();
char input = s.charAt(0);
```

Also just a tip, instead of manually coding each individual JButton for the GUI keyboard, you could create an array containing all 26 letters and then create the buttons and attach listeners using a for loop. This would significantly reduce the amount of code you have to write.

---

New Edit: creating and setting up lots of similar objects

(Also I noticed you created an array to store the buttons as well as a `buttonLetters`array - this isn't necessary unless you have changed your code to utlise an array of buttons)

The important thing to note here is that `ActionListener` is an object in Java so it can be defined to store data and other method definitions like any other class. Personally I would prefer to write an inner class that extends `ActionListener` to store the letter that each button represents.

```
//define this inner class outside of the methods
class KeyboardListener extends ActionListener {
    //field type depends on your buttonLetters array (not sure if it is chars or Strings)
    private final String letter;

    public KeyboardListener(String letter) {
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    public String getLetter() {
        return letter;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        //do something when button is clicked
        //you can make use of the getLetter() method to retrieve the letter
    }
}

//this goes in the for loop when creating each button
    JButton btnX = new JButton(new KeyboardListener(buttonLetters[i]));
    //add button to interface and anything else
```

Note: one of the JButton constructors can take any class that implements the `Action` interface (or extends `ActionListener` in this case) to add it upon creation rather than having to call `addActionListener()`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers I will try these in my code.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem! :) the less you write, the better!

Comment: So I changed the code for adding the buttons, from adding them individually to using a loop to do it.  But now I am not sure how to add the listeners, this is the code that I have changed above.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my answer with an example of how to define ActionListener classes - there are probably many other approaches to this! Don't forget to mark the answer if it has answered your question :)

Comment: So I have edited the code (incl all the code above).  But I am getting the following error - "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The constructor JButton(MouseClick.KeyboardListener) is undefined

 at guis.MouseClick.<init>(MouseClick.java:198)
 at guis.TestMouseClick.main(TestMouseClick.java:11)"